# symfony2: fill request data into form

Tags: symfony

I've tried to pass GET parameter to fill default values of form fields:

```
Form Fields: field1, field2
URL: http://localhost:8000/some_entity/new?field1=default
```

In the controller if tried to bind the parameters to the form:

```
public function newAction(Request $request) {
   $entity = new Entity();
   $form = $this->createCreateForm($entity);

   // first try
   $request->request->set('field1', $_GET['field1']);
   $form->handleRequest($request);

   // second try
   $form->setData(array('field1' => $_GET['field1']));

   // this works, but it's useless in my case
   $entity->setField1($_GET['field1']);
   $form->setData($entity);

   [...]
}
```

Can you tell me how I can do this?

**EDIT:**
I need this because this controller is not used for this entity exclusively. In a second step, I want to provide a button to add "child values" of joining entities. E.g. add a `comment` to a `post` providing the dedicated post id through `$_GET` vars to be selected automatically.

Comment: How about passing the fields to your template and using `<input ... value="{{ field1 }}">` ? I don't understand why you can't use your `entity` here, since it's the correct solution ...

Comment: Thanks for you answer, I've updated my post.

Comment: Looks like you trying to do complicated things whereas the solution is really simple. Are you saying your want only one Action for many different behaviours / routes ? That's definitely not what you should do

Comment: In a symfony2 context, never use `$_GET`. And please read the documentation concerning [requests and responses](http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/http_fundamentals.html).

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way is to pass these values to the entity. And you can get the _GET values from the request object like below.

```
$entity = new Entity();
$entity->setField1($request->query->get('field1'));
//...
$form = $this->createCreateForm($entity);
```